# Syntax issue with php and a sqlite insert statement

Tags: php, sqlite

This code gives me an error when I try to insert Cat and Purr.  The tutorial didn't have a double quotation mark, but their code didn't work either.  This has to be a syntax issue of some sort.

```
message('creating the db Object');
    $db = new bwSQLite3(DB_FILENAME, TABLE_NAME);
    $tn = TABLE_NAME;
    message('creating the table');
    $db->sql_do("Drop table if exists $tn");
    $db->sql_do("create table $tn ( id integer primary key, animal text, sound text )");
    //insert some records
    $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?), 'cat', 'Purr' "); //right here issues
    $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?), 'dog', 'Woof' ");
    $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?), 'duck', 'Quack' ");
    $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?), 'bear', 'Grr' ");
    message('there are %d rows in the table', $db->count_recs());
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Here is the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'insert' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ExerciseFiles\Chap01\create.php on line 42

Comment: Please add your error to your question.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'insert' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ExerciseFiles\Chap01\create.php on line 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?), 'cat', 'Purr' "); //right here issues
```

should be

```
 $db->sql_do("insert into $tn (animal, sound) values (?, ?)", 'cat', 'Purr');
```

look at the syntax highlighting.

Also it sounds like you don't understand how PHP works with strings, try this to see the difference:

```
$my_name = 'Matt';
echo 'Hello $my_name.';
echo "Hello $my_name.";
```

Comment: Yes, I see it. I appreciate the tutorial.   ' ' = literal string.  " " used for commands and strings.

Comment: Also @SDJ, the syntax error was due to having a spurious `"` at the end of the `sql_do` parameters.  You wanted to double quote the parameterized query ( the first argument) , and then provide the parameter values ( the remaining arguments ).    Understanding `'` vs `"` is valuable, but the real source of the issues here, was the fact that both the parameterized query and the parameters' values were put all within one double quoted string.